# Group close values

Tags: javascript

I'd like to group the values in an Array or group the indices in the following way:
If the difference between two values is smaller than a treshold value, then the two values will grouped together, but if a third value is also within the treshold to the second one, then the tree numbers must be grouped together.
For example I have the Array [1,2,3,50,51,52,53,98,99] and the treshold=1 then my output should be like this: group1=[1,2,3] group2=[50,51,52,53] group3=[98,99], or with the indices: group1=[0,1,2] group2=[3,4,5,6] group3=[7,8]

Any ideas how to achieve that? Im stucked with duplication removal and the whole grouping process.

Comment: seems like a simple loop and comparing. What did you try?

Comment: Tried two loops nested into each other

'code'for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
            for (var j=0; j<values.length; j++) {
                if(Math.abs(values[i]-values[j])<=treshold && i!=j && overlapValues.indexOf(i)==-1){
                   overlapValues.push(j);
                } 
            }
        }

Comment: Post the code and we will be able to look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```js
// ES6 version:
 function group(arr, treshold) {
  arr.sort((a,b)=> a - b) // sort numbers
  arr = Array.from(new Set(arr)) // remove duplicates
  let out = [[]] // create output array
  let c = 0 // counter for groups
  arr.forEach((v,i) => {
   out[c].push(v) //add value to the current group
   if (arr[i + 1]-v > treshold) {
    c++ // if next value is out of treshold incrase the counter
    out[c] = []
   }
   
  })
  return out
 }

console.log(group([1,2,3,50,51,52,80,34,2,0], 1))
```

Comment: Thank you, it works like charm. I will inspect the code and get smarter. =)
Saved my day, thank you again!

Comment: Your welcome, if you think my answer has solved your problem please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is: create an array of groups. Each group is an object with three elements: `min`, `max` and `items`.

Iterate the groups and compare with `min` and `max`. If the number that you are comparing does not fit in any existing group, create a new group (`min` and `max` will be equal to the current number and `items` will be an array with one element, the current number) and `push()` it to the array of groups.